# How composite materials used in space tech?

Tags: spacex, nasa, spacecraft, composite-materials

guys, my name is Muhamed-Kanapiya. Now I am studying at Eurasian National University in Astana, and my specialization is Space vehicles and technologies. My master`s work about using composite materials in space tech, and improving methods of them. My question is can you share with me information about composite materials in space tech, how you use them, calculations, graphs, and other data? Which I can use in my master's work.

Comment: Hi Muhamed. This question is much too broad for Stack Exchange. SE is a place where you can get answers to specific questions, not a place to ask for a huge amount of resources. Try searching for this information on sites like Google Scholar instead.

Comment: Make your question more specific!

Comment: You can also search this site for "composite" to get an idea what other questions on the that topic look like https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=composite

Comment: thanks, guys, I also tried Quora, but they don't believe that my name is Muhamed-Kanapiya